# SQLAlchemy and filtering polymorphic queries

Tags: inheritance, sqlalchemy, polymorphic-associations, flask-sqlalchemy

I've the classes `Node` and `Leaf (Node)` as shown below:

```
class Node (db.Model):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'node', 'polymorphic_on':'type'}
    id = db.Column (db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column ('type', db.String (16))

    root_id = db.Column (db.Integer, db.ForeignKey (id))
    nodes = db.relationship ('Node',
        cascade='all', lazy='dynamic',
        primaryjoin='Node.root_id==Node.id',
        backref=db.backref('root', remote_side=id))
    leafs = db.relationship ('Leaf',
        cascade='all', lazy='dynamic',
        primaryjoin='Leaf.root_id==Node.id')

    def __init__ (self, root):
        self.root = root
```

and

```
class Leaf (Node):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'leaf'}
    leaf_id = db.Column (db.Integer, db.ForeignKey ('node.id'), primary_key=True)

    def __init__ (self, root):
        super (Leaf, self).__init__ (root)
```

with the following properties (excerpt from my tests):

```
def test_polymorphic (self):
    base_node, leaf_of_base, node_of_base, leaf_of_node = self.create ()
    self.commit ([base_node, leaf_of_base, node_of_base, leaf_of_node])

    leaf, node = base_node.nodes.all ()

    self.assertEqual (type (leaf), Leaf)
    self.assertTrue (isinstance (leaf, Node))
    self.assertTrue (isinstance (leaf, Leaf))

    self.assertEqual (type (node), Node)
    self.assertTrue (isinstance (node, Node))
    self.assertFalse (isinstance (node, Leaf))
```

So `Node.nodes` **includes** leaf objects (which is what I want), and `Node.leafs` results in **only** leaf objects (that's also fine).

Now, I'd like to introduce `Node.nodes_except_leafs`, which I did like:

```
class Node (db.Model):
    ...
    nodes_except_leafs = property (lambda self: self.nodes.filter_by (type='node'))
```

This actually works, but I don't think it is the best solution possible, since using this approach, I'd miss a node of e.g. the following type:

```
class NodeEx (Node):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'nodeex'}
    nodex_id = db.Column (db.Integer, db.ForeignKey ('node.id'), primary_key=True)

    def __init__ (self, root):
        super (NodeEx, self).__init__ (root)
```

Since `Node.nodes.filter_by (type='node')` would miss all `NodeEx` objects with `NodeEx.type == 'nodeex'`.

What would be a better solution for `Node.nodes_except_leafs` that returns all non-leaf-or-derivations-of-leaf objects (derived possibly from a sub-class of `Node`)? Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the below:

```
class Node (db.Model):
    ...
    # original
    nodes_except_leafs = property (lambda self: self.nodes.filter(Node.type != 'leaf'))

    # use outer join (to class) to filter out the Leaf(++)
    nodes_except_leafs = property (lambda self: self.nodes.outerjoin(Leaf, Node.id == Leaf.leaf_id).filter(Leaf.id == None))
```

Comment: Thx for the answer: It works in principle, but is actually not what I'm looking for, since your suggestion fails to omit leafs which have been instantiated using a sub-class of `Leaf` e.g. `leafex = LeafEx (..)` where `class LeafEx (Leaf)` with `LeafEx.type == 'leafex'`. (tested)

Comment: updated the answer with version that solves the concerns expressed